# Is it possible to check for the Visual C++ runtime at startup of an MFC application?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, runtime

When an MFC application starts, is it possible to check for the Visual C++ runtime before the "application configuration" error is displayed?

I assume it must be done via pure Win32 API at some point before the CRT loads.

Comment: +1 Good question.  I don't think you can, but if someone knows how to do it, I'd like to know too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is coming from the operating system, before your program is even finished loading. There is no part of the program, not even initialization, which has run yet. Thus no way your program can eliminate the error message by itself.

**Edit:** You might be able to set the runtime DLL as a [delay-loaded DLL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/151kt790.aspx) to get your program loaded in the absence of the runtime. Then you'd have to substitute your own function for the .exe entry point and have it check for the existence of the runtime library. There are many technical difficulties associated with this approach, and I'm not even sure it would work at all - but it might be possible.

Answer (score -1):

Well, you get that error because you're missing the redistributables. So instead of trying something like that, you should rather install the VC++ redistributables from Microsoft (as prerequisite for your application). I used to keep a list of the downloads [here](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=494136).

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.

Comment: Why not? He doesn't have the runtime, he should install the runtime as a prerequisite, make sure it exists, not finding obscure solutions.

Comment: The question was not "Why does my app crash when I attempt to start it, and how can I fix this?" but "Can I detect the presence/absence of the Visual C++ runtime when my app starts?"  From the question, it's pretty clear that Aidan knows what's causing the crash.